# How to uninstall berrybrew—perlbrew for Windows?

Tags: perl, uninstallation, berrybrew

I have been running `berrybrew` on Windows
(here's the [home page](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steve_bertrand/2016/07/berrybrew-the-perlbrew-for-windows-rewritten-and-enhanced.html)  and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew)).
I'm having some trouble with it and I want to uninstall and reinstall it, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I am hoping it is as simple as just deleting the directory where it was installed and `C:\berrybrew`, which is where it seems to keep files, but I don't know for sure. The instructions contain installation instructions, but no *uninstallation* instructions.

Comment: This is a really good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: [berrybrew](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew) author here...

To uninstall and return your system back to default:

- `berrybrew off`
- `berrybrew unconfig`
- then delete the directory you downloaded it to, as well as the installation directory (by default, `C:\berrybrew`)
- Edit your PATH variable to remove any entries that start with `C:\berrybrew` (or the base install directory if you've changed it from the default). One of the path entries will point to `C:\berrybrew\bin`, and there may be one more that points to the currently in-use Perl installation (also under `C:\berrybrew\...`). Technically speaking, there shouldn't be any after the first two commands are run, but one should always verify

Essentially, there's really nothing to "uninstall". It comes down to removing `$ENV{PATH}` ie. specific environment variables that point to a) berrybrew.exe binary itself, and b) the Perl installation that you last used.

I will update the documentation to provide more clarity in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add some instructions here about what specifically to remove from the path variables?

Comment: Any entries that start with `C:\berrybrew` (or the base install directory if you've changed it from the default). One of the path entries will point to `c:\berrybrew\bin`, and there may be one more that points to the currently in-use Perl installation (also under `C:\berrybrew\...`).

Comment: Thanks. I added that as a step in your post.

Comment: @Stephen I greatly appreciate your patience here. 'berrybrew' has been a massive undertaking to say the least, and I had to learn the C# language to ensure its existence. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Thank YOU! berrybrew is awesome.